# excel vba find property with other characters

Tags: excel, vba, find

In the codes, I want to find a specific value's column number in a worksheet and that value will change almost everyday. And sometimes it will contain characters like "İ", "Ş", "#" and other staff.

The problem is, find property doesn't work with those letters and I cannot get that cells column number.

Here are the codes which I'm trying to find the position;

```
For x = 2 To LastRowB

Set xr = Worksheets("Check").Range("T" & x & ":BQ" & x & "").Find(Check_Value)

If Not (xr Is Nothing) Then

Dim xa As String
xa = Split(xr.Address, "$")

xCheck_Column = xa(1) + 1
xTotal_First = Worksheets("Check").Cells(x, xCheck_Column).Value

e = e + xTotal_First

End If

Next x
```

At debug mode, I see that Check_Value doesn't come correctly. It should come with other characters like Ş and İ but it comes as S and I.

EDIT:

With changing the Check_Value like this;

```
    Dim Check_Value As String
    Dim xr As Range
        Check_Value = Worksheets("Check_Test").Range("P5").Value

Set xr = Worksheets("Check").Range(""T" & x & ":BQ" & x & "").Find(Check_Value)
Dim xa As Long
xa = xr.Column
```

I still cannot get the column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Dim xa As String
xa = Split(xr.Address, "$")
xCheck_Column = xa(1) + 1
```

use

```
Dim xa As long
xa = xr.Column
xCheck_Column = xa + 1
```

or

```
Dim xa
xa = Split(xr.Address, "$")
xCheck_Column = xa(2) + 1
```

***EDIT :***

When I use below code I get the desired result. See image.

```
Sub t()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String
    str = "SOY" & ChrW(304) & "S"
    Set rng = Range("A1:O10").Find(str)
    MsgBox "Column no. " & rng.Column
End Sub
```

[image]

---

***EDIT 2 :*** I am able to get the value of `str` from sheet and then find. See below.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String
    str = Range("A1").Value
    Set rng = Range("D1:O10").Find(str)
    MsgBox "Column no. " & rng.Column
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. But the main problem in here is that, find property doesn't work quite well. With debug mode, I can see that it comes as xr = nothing. But I know that it should bring value.

Comment: @Bildircin13 - How are you assigning value to `Check_Value`, from sheet or in code?

Comment: Right now, because I am trying to write the codes, the value is in the codes. It's written as  SOY" & ChrW(304) & "S". So it shout come like " SOYİS" but at find value, it comes as "SOYIS" so it doesn't find SOYIS value in the worksheet.

Comment: But even when I get the value of "Check_Value" from worksheet, it doesn't matter. It comes as "SOYIS" and I don't know why..

Comment: I opened a new module to test, but I don't know why, with your codes, I still get str = "SOYIS", not "SOYİS", but it gives me the correct answer... It's interesting. @Mrig

Comment: @Bildircin13 - `ChrW` represents Unicode characters and I guess it can not be displayed in VBE but works well in sheets.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. :)

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't give the correct answer, if I get the value of str from worksheet. In the end, the value of "Check_Value" will come from a userform, and it doesn't work with a value from worksheet. I am trying to make this work with, small and big letters like; "SoyİS". @Mrig

Comment: It works at other parts of my codes like worksheetfunction.countif, but to find the value, I still couldn't get it.

Comment: @Bildircin13 - I am able to get the value of `str` from sheet and then find. See edit2.

Comment: I found the problem I believe. The range that I am looking for have the value I am looking for but it has as a result in formula. It's not written in there. It's just a formula. When I write there the value, it finds it. Otherwise, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea to overcome this problem? @Mrig

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156008/discussion-between-mrig-and-bildircin13).